# MQTT in-depth analysis and performance testing . Need simulation tools and examples

Tags: networking, simulation, mqtt, iot

I an working on a project to carry on an in-depth analysis of the MQTT protocol for IOT devices . Something like delay , bandwidth , roundtrip , packet drops , QOS , etc .

Can you suggest me some software with examples to simulate a simple client broker scenario ? .

I would run the test on an arduino based sensor nodes , sending data to a raspberry pi acting as the gateway . Also i wish to use Eclipse Paho as the client and HiveMQ / Mosquitto as the broker . 
It would be better if you can give examples that can support the hardware that i am using .

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is for asking specific programming questions, not for recommendations on which software to use to sticker a problem.

Comment: Having said that look at the Core network emulation framework from NRL, it supports plugging real hardware into emulated networks